# IE7 shrinking inputs issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some inputs which I am validation on keyup and it works perfectly well except in IE7 where it shrinks the input with each keystroke.

I have debugged the code to find out that it is the jQUery .addClass/.removeClass which is causing the effect.

It's just a plain old input, nothing special.

Any ideas?

```
$('input#myId').bind('keyup blur',function(){
        var _this = $(this);          
        if(_this.val().match(/^[0-9()\-\+\ ]+$/i)== null){
            _this.addClass('errorColor');               
        }else{
            _this.removeClass('errorColor');               
        }
});
```

**EDIT:**

I finally found the answer! It turns out that it was the boxsizing.htc script. This script dynamically converts the padding, margin AND border to be included within the elements height and width. Each time I typed in the input it tried to apply the class which triggered the onupdate event and refresh the elements size. In my CSS I was slightly lazy and had added the important declaration to the errorClass rule, purely to make sure it had the highest posible specificity. It was that importance that reveals a slight bug in the boxsizing code as it then counts the border width incrementally (or more simply it doesn't remove it from the previous calculation).

I'll try to get an example up asap.

Comment: Can you show the css related to the class you are adding and removing?

Comment: also make a fiddle so we can see this behavior

Comment: If you are setting a `height` in your `errorColor` class, its not going to work on ie7. Use `padding` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was boxsizing.htc script. Do not use the !important declaration with this script as it increments the values when calculating a refresh... hence the shrinking inputs

Answer (score 1):

probably jQuery has nothing to do with the issue in IE7. It is more likely the issue is due to CSS associated with `errorColor` class.

Answer (score 0):

My best guesses without more data are:

a) The class is failing getting removed and keeps accumulating on the element.

b) This is some IE7 100% width weirdness, try 99% or auto and see if it helps.

Comment: I guess, a guess should be a comment :)

Comment: Is there a StackOverflow etiquette page? I don't always know what one should be doing on this site in various situations. The main reason I answered is because the questioner didn't provide enough info to make anything but n educated guesses. Others have called for more info via comments, but none has materialized. The answer before mine, the one starting with "probably..." is not really any different. Aren't most StackOverflow questions guesses in a sense anyways? Where folks attempt at providing a solution (often failing) and only one is chosen.

Comment: Serhiy, an educated guess is always better than nothing!